# How to set JAVA_HOME for all users for "elasticsearch" program?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to set JAVA_HOME for `elasticsearch` but no luck till now.

I tried to set it in `.bashrc`, `etc/environment`, `etc/.profile` all fail.

this is the command I use to run elasticsearch:

`sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`

I tried debug the JAVA_HOME variable in terminal like this:

1. `echo $JAVA_HOME`
2. `sudo echo $JAVA_HOME`

I got the result `/home/mockie/softwares/jdk1.8.0_45` for the both which is correct path for my JAVA.

I also tried debug `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` like this:

```
echo "$JAVA_HOME/dodol"
exit 1
```

and the result was empty and only return "/dodol".

this is full code for `etc/init.d/elasticsearch` :
https://gist.github.com/mockiemockiz/c9547aee791ee04c2e1d

and this is my `etc/environment`:

```
    PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

    JAVA_HOME=/home/mockie/softwares/jdk1.8.0_45
```

but when I try this :

```
$ sudo su
$ /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

and it works! but what I want is to use `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start` without `sudo su` first. is it possible?

Comment: After set in `/etc/enviroment`, you reboot the system?

Comment: I havent tried it, btw what the different with `etc/environment` and `etc/.bashrc`? is it correct `home/mockie/.bashrc` is just for my profile?

Comment: If your issue is solved, please put up an answer explaining how did you solve it..that will be helpful for future readers..also the answer given already seems legit to me apart from the fact that you don't have to restart the system..you can also select the answer as accepted so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Comment: but what I'm asking is I want to use `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start` without `sudo su` first. is it possible?

Comment: After setting `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment` do `source /etc/environment` and then check..

Comment: still doesn't work with reboot or `source /etc/environment`

Comment: WHats the error you are having ?

Comment: `Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME` would you see the elasticsearch full code ? it might help you to answer my question.

Comment: here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spinscale/elasticsearch/issue-3452-debian-init-script/src/deb/init.d/elasticsearch

Comment: Whats the content of `/etc/default/elasticsearch` ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mockiemockiz/62b56de9c8072f370e26 but when i add `JAVA_HOME=/home/mockie/softwares/jdk1.8.0_45` in top of the file, i got this error ` * Starting Elasticsearch Server                                                touch: cannot touch ‘/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Whats the output of `[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ] && echo 'FOUND'` ?

Comment: I try edit elasticsearch like this `
[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ] && echo 'FOUND'
echo "dodol"
exit 1` and it return `dodol`. I also try again `echo $JAVA_HOME`  IN TERMINAL w/without sudo i got the path correct path `/home/mockie/softwares/jdk1.8.0_45`

Comment: Put exactly `JAVA_HOME='/home/mockie/softwares/jdk1.8.0_45'` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` , then run the command and give the full command and output..

Comment: here https://gist.github.com/mockiemockiz/3bd276963eb91c12c309 the error is the result file.

Comment: Whats the output of `grep '^PID_FILE\|^NAME' /etc/init.d/elasticsearch` ?

Comment: NAME=elasticsearch
PID_FILE="$PID_DIR/$NAME.pid"

Comment: Change `PID_FILE="$PID_DIR/$NAME.pid"` to `PID_FILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid` ..why did you change these..its really hard to sort out these if you keep changing things like this..

Comment: i didnt do anything, it was the result of the command you gave me. I didnt edit any file.

Comment: you gave me this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spinscale/elasticsearch/issue-3452-debian-init-script/src/deb/init.d/elasticsearch and your getting different result..anyway make the change..

Comment: I got that source from google, okay maybe that one different from this https://gist.github.com/mockiemockiz/c9547aee791ee04c2e1d <-- this is from my pc. I'm sorry

Comment: Change the line `mkdir -p "$LOG_DIR" "$DATA_DIR" "$WORK_DIR" && chown "$ES_USER":"$ES_GROUP" "$LOG_DIR" "$DATA_DIR"` to `mkdir -p "$PID_DIR" "$LOG_DIR" "$DATA_DIR" "$WORK_DIR" && chown "$ES_USER":"$ES_GROUP" "$PID_DIR" "$LOG_DIR" "$DATA_DIR"`

Comment: i dont want to edit the core source.. hmm maybe I want to ask this on their repository instead. :( thanks very much heemayl you really helped me this far :)

Comment: Let me give you the idea..the `PID_DIR` is set as `/var/run/elasticsearch` but there is no such directory..so when the `PID_FILE` is trying to create a file in `$PID_DIR` as `$PID_DIR/elasticsearch.pid` it is getting `cannot touch ‘/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid’: No such file or directory` error as the directory `/var/run/elasticsearch` does not exists already..if you want i can put up an answer mentioning this and then you can ask a different question if not solved already..

Comment: yes sure, please. btw I'm wondering why $JAVA_HOME is empty when debugging /etc/init.d/elasticsearch ? do you have idea why? is this something related to user or something? since I tried in terminal `echo $JAVA_HOME` with or without sudo and it works.

Comment: It is the script `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch`..it is setting its own `JAVA_HOME`..if not set in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` it will try set it manually, otherwise left it blank.check line 46 to 54 of the script..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the SysV script `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` itself.

In the script the `PID_DIR` variable is set as :

```
PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch
```

but there is no such directory exists and there is command to create it in the script too.

The `NAME` and `PID_FILE` are set as:

```
NAME=elasticsearch
PID_FILE="$PID_DIR/$NAME.pid"
```

So when the `PID_FILE` is trying to create a file `"$PID_DIR/$NAME.pid"` (`/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticseach.pid`) in `$PID_DIR` (`/var/run/elasticsearch/`), it is getting:

```
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid’: No such file or directory
```

error as the directory `/var/run/elasticsearch` does not exists already.

About the `JAVA_HOME` variable, the script `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` is not using the system's variable rather using/creating its own version of the variable that is well defined in the script.

According to the script, if `JAVA_HOME` is not set in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` it will try to set it manually by searching for certain files in certain directories, otherwise it will left it blank.

Comment: @Kakashi Glad i could help  :)

Comment: according to this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11594 this issue is a bug. and as you pointing out the problem above I just need to change PID_DIR to `/var/run` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` so it doesn't need to create `elasticsearch` directory anymore. I'm still wondering why it worked at the first time with `sudo su` :( that was why i tought it's permission problem or something. at least I learned some bash command from this.

Comment: @Kakashi Yeah.. i was pondering that too..hard to reach a colclusion now though..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what I did was to create a /etc/default/elastic file with the next line inside:

```
JAVA_HOME=/pathto/jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

You can set system-wide environmental variables with three ways:

- /etc/environment
- /etc/profile
- /etc/profile.d/*.sh

You could use for example /etc/profile.
Execute this on your machine

```
sudo echo "JAVA_HOME=/home/mockie/softwares/jdk1.8.0_45" >> /etc/profile
```

Comment: `profile` or  `.profile` and which one the correct name? most of answer out there it always started with a dot.

Comment: i try edit etc/profile like this: 
`export JAVA_HOME=/home/mockie/softwares/jdk1.8.0_45
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin` and still error

Comment: @Kakashi Do not forget / at the beginning.

Comment: sorry i mean `/etc/profile` and still doesnt work. i already checked it in history command and what I edited is /etc/profile with slash at the beginning and doesnt work.

Comment: Do you have the folder profile.d? If not create it and create a new file in it with .sh extension and try to add export for JAVA_HOME inside it. Try to restart the server too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, the solutions provided above probably work.
however in case anybody wants to do the thing without restarting the server
having *just* installed java, you can do what I did (which is probably wrong, but it worked).

Modify:

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/elasticsearch.service
```

add this line:

```
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.4/
```

in the [service] section
You may have to replace /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.4/ with your actual java installation.

I hope this helps, and I apologise to the elasticsearch team for modifying their files, clearly I have no business modifying default files.